# Web App Authentication for REST API Backend

Tags: java, security, rest, jersey, hmac

I am currently in the early stages of creating a web application (HTML5, JS, etc.) that uses a REST API on the backend (Java, specifically Jersey v1.18). The nature of the data that will be stored is highly sensitive, so security is something that I’ve started looking at, even though the application is only in the early stages. The eventual goal will be to have native mobile applications as well, and to potentially provide access to the data for external clients via the same API.

In my research thus far, I have identified a variety of authentication methods, including HTTP Basic, token-based, session cookie, OAuth, HMAC, etc. The key component here is that the REST API will be primarily accessed by users, rather than other applications or backends. Thus, having a “login/logout” equivalent is important, and this boils down to user level authentication.

So far, HMAC authentication looks to be the most promising, as we have no plans to integrate with any OAuth provider at this moment.

I have already read through dozens of SO posts, as well as articles such as:
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/
http://www.errant.me.uk/blog/2013/04/authenticating-restful-web-applications/ (note: this is clearly bad, as salting with the username is not recommended)

Ideally, HMAC seems like the way to go, but I have yet to see a recommended approach to handling the shared secret. The idea of using a resource to validate credentials, which then provides a token/nonce to be used with the HMAC scheme, seems to be an option, but I’m questioning the advantages over just using this token/nonce strictly as a token.

I know that HMAC authentication for a REST API has been discussed at length, but when used in conjunction with the authentication details that users have come to expect (username, email, password, etc.), is there any recommended approach that doesn’t require a pre-shared secret key?

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily an opinion-based question, but I'll offer my two cents: just go for a session cookie.

If your primary audience is humans, and you don't need to integrate with third parties, don't bother with OAuth. Just make sure your API is only available over HTTPS, and issue a session token that the server can revoke after login. Strictly speaking it doesn't need to be a cookie; I've seen APIs that stash the token in HTML5 session storage and provide it in the Authorization header or as a query param.

If you have SSL set up properly, your users will get the expected padlock in the browser, and you'll be safe from anyone in between you and the client. If the client is compromised, you're screwed anyways. And since the client can't keep a secret, there aren't a lot of advantages to more complex HMAC schemes.

Comment: Is there any framework you would recommend that works well with Jersey? I've looked at Apache Shiro, Spring Security, Apache Oltu, and using the HTTP Basic auth as part of Jersey.

Comment: For something this simple, I would use a basic servlet filter or similar. Just send requests to authenticated endpoints to the filter first and reject with a 401 if there's no token. Obviously if you have domain-specific authorization logic you'll still need to handle that on a per-resource basis.